# How is the value of request.user.id determined?

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

[According to documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user), the value of `request.user.id` set by Django after receiving the request. What information from the request does Django use to determine its value, and does it hit the database to do so?

I'm ultimately looking for an efficient (no extra requests or template tags) method to get a non-secret and persistent unique ID (doesn't necessarily have to be the primary key, preferably not too many characters) for the current user in Javascript and in Django. This unique ID would be prepended to user uploads to S3; since it's unique, one user's filenames will not collide with another user's filenames.

Comment: `request.user` is a `User` object which is fetched from the database. The database is generally what is used to provide persistence for anything... not sure how you can guarantee that without using it.

Comment: To add - Django uses [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) to remember which user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs:

> Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system into request objects.

This is achieved by **AuthenticationMiddleware** in django.

So whenever the `login(request,user)` from `django.contrib.auth` is called, django adds the required data in the session. [[view docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login)

After this, on every request, you get a `request.user` object until you call the `logout(request)`. [[view docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#logout)